# The buttons are overlapped by the iPhone navigation bar in Safari

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, safari, mobile-safari

Here is my style responsible for the navigation buttons at the bottom, the screenshot shows that the buttons overlap

```
#navbar_mobile_extra_links {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #29166F;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[screensoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCoSw.jpg)

Everything works correctly in Chrome:(

Comment: You can add z-index: 9999; in above code. If it doesn't work please share HTML Code as well so that I will configure out the structure.

Comment: @Jagroop The structure can be viewed here https://zaotdih.ru/omsk/places/

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean the bottom bar which appears when page is opened as PWA. This native Safari part and this is not possible to remove it. To resolve this problem you can add small padding at the bottom of mobile navigation only on Safari browser, by using below CSS rule:

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root #navbar_mobile_extra_links {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```